# Magento 2.X - "Invalid Customer Address Id" comes randomly for the customers on checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer-account, shipping-address, customer-address

I've faced an issue in **Magento 2.2.9** says `"Invalid Customer address id XXXX"` randomly for the registered customers on the website.

```
[2019-08-09 02:44:33] main.CRITICAL: Invalid customer address id XXXXXX {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Invalid customer address id 313116 at /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php:77)"} []
```

How to fix this issue coming on the Magento 2?

I have checked this further and found that this issue is because of the customer quote which is active and does not have an entry in the quote_address table.

How can we fix this?

Update: This issue is still exists in Magento 2.4.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've checked it further and fixed this issue by overriding Magento's **validateForCart** function.

```
/**
 * Validate address to be used for cart.
 *
 * @param CartInterface $cart
 * @param AddressInterface $address
 * @return void
 */
public function validateForCart(CartInterface $cart, AddressInterface $address)
{
    $this->doValidate($address, $cart->getCustomer()->getId() ? $cart->getCustomer()->getId() : null);
}
```

The issue is with the customer Id passing in the function is null for the customers facing this issue.

> EDIT

As per https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/26637, I've optimized the `validateForCart` function code.

```
public function validateForCart(CartInterface $cart, AddressInterface $address): void
{
    $this->doValidate($address, $cart->getCustomer()->getId() ?: null);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your full code how did you override the validateForCart ? I have tried with plugin/preference but facing errors.

Comment: I've done this with preference.

Comment: Okay thanks I have already done it with preference.

Comment: @DineshRajput can you share full code? I have this same issue.

Comment: I have shared my full code @RajeshNagappan

Comment: <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteAddressValidator" type="YOURVENDOR\YOURMODULE\Model\QuoteAddressValidator"/> --> Change top of file namespace YOURVENDOR\YOURMODULE\Model; -> run mag:di:compile

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue, used plugin to solve this.

In di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteAddressValidator">
        <plugin name="disableguestcheck" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\QuoteAddressValidatorPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

In the pLugin Class

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteAddressValidator;

class QuoteAddressValidatorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param QuoteAddressValidator $subject
     * @param CartInterface $cart
     * @param AddressInterface $address
     */
    public function beforeValidateForCart(
        QuoteAddressValidator $subject,
        CartInterface $cart,
        AddressInterface $address
    ): void {
        if ($cart->getCustomer()->getId()) {
            $cart->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
        }
    }
}
```

One More thing I notice once the plugin is executed It also corrects the `customer_is_guest` in `Quote` table in database.

Comment: Perfect!!! Can you please share your Magento version for which you've implemented the fix?

Comment: Magento Version 2.4.2

Comment: I had issue in 2.4.3-p1. To save time in future I've created extension on github https://github.com/DominicWatts/InvalidCustomerAddressId

Answer (score 4):

Below is my code for preference:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteAddressValidator" type="Vendor\Module\Model\QuoteAddressValidator" />
</config>
```

Below is the model to override:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;

/**
 * Quote shipping/billing address validator service.
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CookieAndSessionMisuse)
 */
class QuoteAddressValidator extends \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteAddressValidator
{
/**
 * Address factory.
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $addressRepository;

/**
 * Customer repository.
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $customerRepository;

/**
 * @deprecated 101.1.1 This class is not a part of HTML presentation layer and should not use sessions.
 */
protected $customerSession;

/**
 * Constructs a quote shipping address validator service object.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository Customer repository.
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

/**
 * Validate address.
 *
 * @param AddressInterface $address
 * @param int|null $customerId Cart belongs to
 * @return void
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException The specified address belongs to another customer.
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException The specified customer ID or address ID is not valid.
 */
private function doValidate(AddressInterface $address, ?int $customerId): void
{
    //validate customer id
    if ($customerId) {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        if (!$customer->getId()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(
                __('Invalid customer id %1', $customerId)
            );
        }
    }

    if ($address->getCustomerAddressId()) {
        //Existing address cannot belong to a guest
        if (!$customerId) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(
                __('Invalid customer address id %1', $address->getCustomerAddressId())
            );
        }
        //Validating address ID
        try {
            $this->addressRepository->getById($address->getCustomerAddressId());
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(
                __('Invalid address id %1', $address->getId())
            );
        }
        //Finding available customer's addresses
        $applicableAddressIds = array_map(function ($address) {
            /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address */
            return $address->getId();
        }, $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId)->getAddresses());
        if (!in_array($address->getCustomerAddressId(), $applicableAddressIds)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(
                __('Invalid customer address id %1', $address->getCustomerAddressId())
            );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Validates the fields in a specified address data object.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $addressData The address data object.
 * @return bool
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException The specified address belongs to another customer.
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException The specified customer ID or address ID is not valid.
 */
public function validate(AddressInterface $addressData)
{
    $this->doValidate($addressData, $addressData->getCustomerId());

    return true;
}

/**
 * Validate address to be used for cart.
 *
 * @param CartInterface $cart
 * @param AddressInterface $address
 * @return void
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException The specified address belongs to another customer.
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException The specified customer ID or address ID is not valid.
 */
/*public function validateForCart(CartInterface $cart, AddressInterface $address): void
{
    $this->doValidate($address, $cart->getCustomerIsGuest() ? null : $cart->getCustomer()->getId());
}*/

public function validateForCart(CartInterface $cart, AddressInterface $address): void
{
    $this->doValidate($address, $cart->getCustomerId() ? $cart->getCustomer()->getId() : null );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error when programmatically creating an quote/order, make sure to set the following if the quote/order should belong to a customer:

```
$quote->setCustomerIsGuest(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23618#issuecomment-929293382
(All credits to ssstankiewicz)

To fix inconsistency at checkout(after login etc. with customer_id and customer_is_guest = 1) can edit vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php:857 (Magento 2.4.2) From:

```
if ($this->_customer) {
    $this->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId());
}
```

To:

```
if ($this->_customer && $this->_customer->getId()) {
    $this->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId());
    $this->setCustomerIsGuest(false);
}
```

Of course via patch or afterBeforeSave plugin:

```
public function afterBeforeSave(MagentoQuote $subject, MagentoQuote $result): MagentoQuote
{
    if ($result->getCustomerId()) {
        $result->setCustomerIsGuest(false);
    }

    return $result;
}
```